# Ttransforming XML using XSLT with count

Tags: xslt

I am trying to transform the following XML using XSLT

Input XML

```
<lst name="facet_pivot">
    <arr name="party-name,entry-number,release-number">
        <lst>
            <str name="field">party-name</str>
            <str name="value">XYZ CONSULTANTS</str>
            <int name="count">348</int>
            <arr name="pivot">
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <null name="value"/>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <null name="value"/>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <null name="value"/>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <str name="value">8300012706</str>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <str name="value">8300012821</str>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <str name="value">8300018075</str>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <str name="value">8300018083</str>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <str name="value">8300018133</str>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <str name="value">8300018141</str>
                    <int name="count">1</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">1</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">entry-number</str>
                    <null name="value"/>
                    <int name="count">270</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">release-number</str>
                            <null name="value"/>
                            <int name="count">270</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
            </arr>
        </lst>
    </arr>
</lst>
```

into something like

required Output XML

```
<reply>
    <party-name>XYZ CONSULTANTS</party-name>
    <count>348</count>
    <no-entry-release-count>4</no-entry-release-count>
</reply>
```

And Iam having issues transforming  .

I have tried using following xsl template

```
    <xsl:for-each select="lst">       
                <ns:party-name><xsl:value-of select="str[@name='value']"/></ns:party-name>
                <ns:shipments-count><xsl:value-of select="int[@name='count']" /></ns:shipments-count>   

                <xsl:for-each select="arr[@name='pivot']">
                    <xsl:if test="lst/null[@name='value'] = '' and lst/arr[@name='pivot']/lst/null[@name='value']/text() = ''">
                        <ns:no-entry-or-line-release-count>
                            <xsl:value-of select ="count(lst/null[@name='value'] = '' and lst/arr[@name='pivot']/lst/null[@name='value']/text() = '')"> </xsl:value-of>        
                        </ns:no-entry-or-line-release-count>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>    
</xsl:template>
```

but count always returns 1.Seems i am doing some thing wrong.
I am not able to figure it out why it is always returning one.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this template to get required counts.

```
<xsl:template match="lst/arr/lst">
        <ns:reply>
            <ns:party-name>
                <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='value']"/>
            </ns:party-name>
            <ns:shipments-count>
                <xsl:value-of select="int[@name='count']" />
            </ns:shipments-count>   
            <ns:no-entry-or-line-release-count>
                <xsl:value-of select ="count(arr[@name='pivot']/lst[count(str[@name='value'])=0]/arr[@name='pivot']/lst/int[@name='count'])"> </xsl:value-of>        
            </ns:no-entry-or-line-release-count>
        </ns:reply>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Very much Ed .I really appreciate your help !